# Using "du" for Total File Size of Certain File Types

Tags: shell, unix, du

I have been using the `du` command to get the size of a directory:

```
du /tmp/dir1
```

This produced the total size of the files:

```
7   /tmp/dir1
```

Which I then parse and use the details.

This folder is full of `.txt` and `txr` files.
I am only interested in the total size of the `*.txt` files.

Is there a way I can odify the `du` command to produce a single line output of the size of just the `*.txt` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a list of files to the `du` command. For example:

```
du -s /tmp/dir1/*.txt
```

A possible solution to getting only the total size is to get the last line of `du`'s output, as in:

```
du -c /tmp/dir1/*.txt | tail -1
```

Comment: A potential problem with this is that this will break if the directory contains too many files (ie. longer than ARG_MAX); which may not be the case now, but I've learned (the hard way) not to rely on shell globbing for these sort of things...

Comment: This is good, but I am looking for a one line output, this will list each `.txt` file and its size, I would like the total.

Comment: if you want the total just use: du -cs /tmp/dir1/*.txt

Comment: Fantastic guys using the `| tail -1` is exactly what I am looking for!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`du` doesn't have an easy way to filter the output; but we can use `find` with `stat` to get the filesize, and then `awk` to sum it up:

```
$ find /tmp/dir1 -name '*.txt' -exec stat -c %s {} + | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Note this will only work on Linux/GNU systems, due to incompatible `stat` arguments.

Comment: Nice solution, I like your thinking.  Sadly though, this didn't work on my particular system.

Comment: @DustinCook This is why should mention your environment in the question :-) UNIX(-like) sytems are not always very portable, unfortunately...

Comment: @DustinCook ;-) You should mention it, anyway, if only to prevent "wrong" answers like this; it wasted your time reading & trying it, and it wastes my time testing it to make sure I got it correct. If you had mentioned "I'm using AIX version foo" for example, I probably would not have bothered, since I'm not sure what AIX does and doesn't support, and would prefer giving no answer over a wrong answer...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--exclude` option:

```
du --exclude '*.krt' /tmp/dir1
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I like the solution, and will definitely use it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**Here are the possible options:**

- If you want the size of each '.txt' file in the same dir (/tmp/dir1).
  And at the end, it will also print the total size of all '.txt' files

> `du -csh *.txt`

- Recursively find the size of each '.txt' file in the given dirs/sub-dirs of any depth and print the total size of all those files at the end

> find  -name "*.txt" -exec du -csh '{}' +

**Note:** you can replace .txt with any other file types

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the size of a directories and files by means of the below command.

Navigate to path(**/tmp/dir1**) **`du -sh *`** or **`du -sh /tmp/dir1`**

- s represents Sum of directories.
- h represents human readable format.